# absolute center with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked all over the place and this seemed to be the best I could find. I am trying to absolute center a `div` with `h2` and `p` tags within.

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.center').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '50%',
    'top': '50%',
    'margin-left': function() {
      return -$(this).outerWidth() / 2
    },
    'margin-top': function() {
      return -$(this).outerHeight() / 2
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
  <h2 class="special">My Title</h2>
</div>
```

I have an `h2` element on my page within a `div` with a class of `center`. I have tried to make the `h2`'s CSS properties `width: 100%; text-align: center;` to try and get it slap back in the middle. It is always more to the right than the left and it is pretty annoying.

I have tried with many fonts to make sure it isn't the font I'm using isn't messing anything up but same results all round. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Post a complete code example please ([mcve]). What does the HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: @j08691: is that enough?

Comment: `width: 100%;` - You shouldn't need that for block elements like `h2`, and it might have undesired results. Just let the element fill the available space itself.

Comment: Write a CSS class and use `.addClass("center-box")` or whatever instead of trying to inline your centering. 

Also, instead of margin, use `transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);`

Comment: Your code is fine so something else is messing with it https://jsfiddle.net/rzmu9gpw/

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look at my code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure CSS would be like this...

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <h2 class="special">My Title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: The above method has given me the exact same result as the method I currently use.

Comment: @JoshMurray Sorry my mistake, Ive updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In such a cases you should provide some DEMO, but you can do what you want only using css like this :

```
.center {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);  // Chrome, Opera 15+,Safari
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);  // IE 9 
    transform: translateX(-50%);  // Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: This never worked - it has moved the `div` to the top left.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.boxUnKnow
{
  

  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%; 
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align:center;

}
h4
{

position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="boxUnKnow"><h4>Box centered</h4></div>
```

is this result that you want/expected?